# Enumerate SQ tag in a DICOM file using Mergecom toolkit c++

Tags: c++, dicom

I want all attributes in a DICOM file to be listed in a tree control with all SQ attributes as sub items in the tree. I was able to list all attributes except that have VR type SQ. Which API of Mergecom is to be used to enumerate the SQ attributes? Please help.

Comment: Are you using the multi-platorm C based MergeCOM-3 API, or the C#/.NET api?

Answer (score 0):

Tough to help without code, but try:

[getValues](http://estore.merge.com/mergecom3/Resources/DICOM/javadoc4-9/mergecom/merge/mcw/MCattributeSet.html#getValues%28int%29)

To get the MCitem objects in the sequence, then iterate on those and include them as children in your tree.